# Tuples of list and string

Tags: python, list, tuples

so given a random list of lists of peoples preferences of the days of the week such that of the 7 positions in each sublist, the first position is worth 6 points, the second 5, the third 4, the fourth 4, the third 2, second 1, and the last does not get any preference points:

```
    days_week=['mon','tues','wed','thurs','fri','sat','sun']

    random_day_list=[['sat','sun','wed','thurs','mon','tues','fri'],['mon','fri','sat','sun','wed','thurs','tues'],['tues','fri','sun','sat','wed','thurs','mon']]
```

The function i am making should output a tuple of the highest scoring day, and a list of the total points of each day in the order of days_week. The output from above would be:

```
    ('sat',[8,7,8,5,10,14])
```

saturday had 14 points so it was the most preferred day in this case.

So far ive thought of:

```
   day_dictionary={'mon':0,'tues':0,'wed':0,'thurs':0,'fri':0,'sat':0,'sun':0}
   for i in random_day_list:
         # getting into the sublist
         for j in i:
              if j in day_dictionary:
                 # stuck here:  whatever position j is in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) if its 
                   0 add 6, 1 add 5, and so on, to day_dictionary[j]
```

and i cant import anything except math witch i doubt i need

Comment: its a question from a python book that stumped me, so ya homework i guess but not assigned im just doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way to keep track of which position you're at. The [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function does that for you!

Try this:

```
day_dictionary={'mon':0,'tues':0,'wed':0,'thurs':0,'fri':0,'sat':0,'sun':0}
for i in random_day_list:
     for position, day in enumerate(i):
         if day in day_dictionary:
             day_dictionary[day] += (6 - position)
```

(As a note for the future, it would probably be better to use [a defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) rather than manually initializing everything to 0. But since you can't import anything, your way will work fine.)